# How can I assign Hex or RGB color to the MvxColor in Android Converter

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

I have converter like below in that I want to return my own Hex or RGB color.

**In iOS**

```
public class PinkSelectedWhiteUnselectedValueConverter : MvxValueConverter<bool, UIColor> {
    UIColor purePink = UIColor.FromRGB(233, 60, 172);
protected override UIColor Convert(bool value, Type targetType,object parameter, CultureInfo culture) {
    return (bool)value ? purePink : UIColor.White;
  }
}
```

it's working fine

**But in Android, it's not working**

```
 public class PinkSelectedWhiteUnSelectedValueConverter : MvxValueConverter<bool, Color> {      
  Color colorPink = (Color)new  System.Drawing.ColorConverter().ConvertFromString("#e93cac");   

   protected override Color Convert(bool value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) {           
  return (bool)value ? colorPink : Color.White;         
   }    
 }
```

Please help me on that thanks in advance.

Comment: why are you not using android graphics color ?

Comment: Thank you very much it's working

Comment: This line was  changed Color purePink = Color.Rgb(233, 60, 172); it's working.

Comment: You can check the ans out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is something like this :

```
Color colorPink = Android.Graphics.Color.ParseColor("#e93cac");
```

or else something like this

```
Color purePink = Color.Rgb((int)r,(int) g,(int) b)
```