# Change popup color Using Xamarin.Android-Emojicon

Tags: xamarin.android

I am trying to use [EmojiIcon](https://github.com/giuseppenovielli/Xamarin.Android-Emojicon)

with my xamarin.Android application I follow the provided setup guids and every thing seems ok,but is there any way to change the background color for emoji popup, it's appearing with a black background i need to change it to match whatsapp one

Thanks in Advance

[image]

here is my implementations in fragments

```
  private void SetupEmojiconPopup(View viewFragment)
        {
            _emojiconPopup = new EmojiconsPopup(viewFragment, Activity);
             _emojiconPopup.SetSizeForSoftKeyboard();
            _emojiconPopup.SetBackgroundDrawable(null);

            _emojiconPopup.EmojiconClicked += (sender, args) =>
            {
                _emojiconEditText.Append(args.P0.Emoji);
            };

            _emojiconPopup.EmojiconBackspaceClicked += (sender, args) =>
            {
                var keyEvent = new KeyEvent(0, 0, 0, Android.Views.Keycode.Del, 0, 0, 0, (int)Android.Views.Keycode.Endcall);
                _emojiconEditText.DispatchKeyEvent(keyEvent);
            };


            _emojiconPopup.DismissEvent += (sender, args) =>
            {

            };

            _emojiconPopup.KeyboardClose += (sender, args) =>
            {
                if (_emojiconPopup.IsShowing)
                {
                    _emojiconPopup.Dismiss();
                }
            };
        }
```

on Emojicon btn click

```
 private void _mEmojiBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            //Show, Close Emoji Keyboard
            if (!_emojiconPopup.IsShowing)
            {

                if (_emojiconPopup.IsKeyBoardOpen().BooleanValue())
                {

                    _emojiconPopup.ShowAtBottom();

            }
                else
                {

                    _emojiconEditText.FocusableInTouchMode = true;
                    _emojiconEditText.RequestFocus();
                    _emojiconPopup.ShowAtBottomPending();

                    var inputMethodManager = Activity.GetSystemService(Context.InputMethodService) as InputMethodManager;
                     inputMethodManager.ShowSoftInput(_emojiconEditText, Android.Views.InputMethods.ShowFlags.Implicit);
                 }

            }
            else
            {

                _emojiconPopup.Dismiss();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Show us how you've implemented this please.

Comment: I update my question @Raimo

Comment: You are explicitly setting the background drawable to null, that's why your background is black. You should set a drawable with the  SetBackgroundDrawable method, or if you just want a solid color, I suppose there is the equivalent SetBackgroundColor method as well?

Comment: actually no there is not method for setbackgroundcolor, there is a read property background with getter only 
I tryed to pass 
         Android.Graphics.Drawables.ColorDrawable gg = new Android.Graphics.Drawables.ColorDrawable(Color.LightGray);
             _emojiconPopup.SetBackgroundDrawable(gg);

but with no success

Comment: Why dont you do it something like this SetBackgroundColor(Android.Graphics.Color.LightGray); and incase you dont understand check how i did it here https://stackoverflow.com/a/49124988/7462031

Comment: there is no SetBackgroundColor function  @G.hakim

Comment: What are the available methods can you tell me please and may be i can help you out

Comment: this class inherit from the PopupWindow java class you can see all allowed method from this link 

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupWindow